# conditional probability for more than two events

Tags: probability

I know how to use conditional probability and multiplication theorm for two events .

But I am confused how to use this for three events .

Can somebody help me with an example .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Conditional probability**: It’s just a double application of the two-event formula, first thinking of $A\cap B$ as a single event:

$$\begin{align*}
P(A\cap B\cap C)&=P\big((A\cap B)\cap C\big)\\
&=P\big(C\mid(A\cap B)\big)P(A\cap B)\\
&=P\big(C\mid(A\cap B)\big)\Big(P(B\mid A)P(A)\Big)\\
&=P(A)P(B\mid A)P(C\mid A\cap B)\;.
\end{align*}$$

**Multiplication rule**: If E, F and G are three events of sample space, we have 
$$\begin{align*}
P(E\cap F\cap G)&=P(E)P(F\mid E)P(G\mid(E\cap F))\\
&=P(E)P(F\mid E)P(G\mid EF)\;.
\end{align*}$$

An example for applying this rule can be in the question: Three cards are drawn successively, without replacement from a pack of $52$ well shuffled cards. What is the probability that first two cards are kings and the third card drawn is an ace?